# Replace fluentd string using regex

Tags: ruby, regex, fluentd

When sending logs, I want to replace the `id` and `pw` values as in:

```
https://m.xxxxx.com/yyyy.xxxx?id=aaaa&pw=cccc
https://m.xxxxx.com/aaaa.xxxx?id=aaaa&pass=cccc
```

with different values such as:

```
https://m.xxxxx.com/yyyy.xxxx?id=*&pw=****
https://m.xxxxx.com/aaaa.xxxx?id=*&pass=****
```

It is difficult to create a plugin. Is it possible to transfer by converting the `id = aaaa` value to `id = ****` using existing `filter_record_transformer` or `grep`? Is it impossible to use `gsub` of `filter_record_transformer`?

Answer (score -1):

```
"https://m.xxxxx.com/yyyy.xxxx?id=aaaa&pw=cccc".
  gsub(/(?<=id=)[^&]+|(?<=pw=)[^&]+/) { |m| '*' * m.length }
#⇒ "https://m.xxxxx.com/yyyy.xxxx?id=****&pw=****"
```

We use [positive lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) here to match exactly `id` and `pw` parts of the query.